# Doing Subtracting on my Rails App with user input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, math

I'm just starting to learn Rails so please forgive the dumb question. In my web app, I was able to set up working models, forms, and view. A user is able to input their decimal answer and it shows on the web page perfectly. However, I want to subtract one user input from another user input. So if the user inputs 100 in one model "post.price" and 10 in another input model "ratings1.content" > I want it to show 90 in the "fprice.content3". Any help that you guys can give me would be so amazing, I feel like the issue might be in my controller for fprice. I have listed below all my relevant code. Thank you again :)

**_form.html "post.price"**

```
<%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.input :image %>
  <%= f.input :price %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

**_form.html "ratings1s.content"**

```
<%= simple_form_for ([@post, @post.ratings1s.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input_field :content %>
<% end %>
```

**_form.html "fprice.content3"**

```
<%= simple_form_for ([@post, @post.fprices.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input_field :content3 %>
<% end %>
```

**Rails Controller "fprices"**

```
class FpricesController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!
  def create
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@fprice = Fprice.create(params[:fprice].permit(:content3))
@fprice.content3 === @post.price - @ratings1.content
@fprice.user_id = current_user.id
@fprice.post_id = @post.id

if @fprice.save
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
else
  render 'new'
end
  end
end
```

**Rails Controller "ratings1s"**

```
class Ratings1sController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!
  def create
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@ratings1 = Ratings1.create(params[:ratings1].permit(:content))
@ratings1.content *= 10
@ratings1.user_id = current_user.id
@ratings1.post_id = @post.id

if @ratings1.save
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
else
  render 'new'
end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that at no point in time are you every defining `@ratings1` object, then you call the `content` method on it while the value of `@ratings1` is nil and thats what cause the error. Maybe something like this should help:

```
class FpricesController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!
  def create
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@fprice = Fprice.create(params[:fprice].permit(:content3))
@ratings1 = @post.ratings1s.last
@fprice.content3 = @post.price - @ratings1.content
@fprice.user_id = current_user.id
@fprice.post_id = @post.id

if @fprice.save
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
else
  render 'new'
end
  end
end
```

I think this line is also a the problem

```
@fprice.content3 === @post.price - @ratings1.content
```

`===` is an equality operator so I don't know why you would have it there replace it with this

```
@fprice.content3 = @post.price - @ratings1.content
```

Comment: Thanks mate, but I get an error saying "undefined method `content' for nil:NilClass" could this be because of what I have in my _form.html for f.price  --  <%= f.input_field :content3 %>?

Comment: you never define `@ratings1` in the controller action

Comment: that's because it has its own seperate controller. Would i still need to list it out in the " fprice controller". If so would it be like this  @ratings1=Ratings1s. I've put my ratings1 controller in the question if that helps thanks again mate

Comment: Yea I dont think that matters you cant call @ratings1 in the `FpricesController` without defining it first

Comment: What would be appropriate way to do that? Im not sure on how to do that Thank you so much mate, I think we are so close

Comment: no prob man, that code makes the assumption that it will always be the last ratings1s on the post record, if that not the case then let me know an I can update.